# Heroku migrate db error unknown column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, heroku, migration

I am working on my ruby on rails project and when I run heroku db:migrate I get an error about how a column doesn't exist.

I know that this is because I had a migration file that I manually edited to remove a column I created beforehand instead of creating a new migration file.

I removed the remove_column line and migrated db my local db but when I migrate it to heroku it still runs the migration file to remove column even though the line is no longer there on the actual file.

I dropped my database and loaded the schema again but the heroku error continues to occur.

Answer (score 0):

Did you push the commit to heroku after changing the file?

Answer (score 0):

### Don't edit Rails database migration files after you have raked a migration using that particular migration file

This was your problem

> I had a migration file that I manually edited to remove a column I created beforehand instead of creating a new migration file.

### Always create a new migration file to elicit a column change

Why? Because the migration files are like a chain of of interconnected links laid in a very specific order that when raked will allow you to re-create your database, to a production server, for example. If you disturb one of those links then that chain required to build your database is broken, as you observed. That's one of the reasons why the migration files have specific time stamps, they are unique entities meant to be created and executed and saved.

### Fixing a broken migration

Now, you have a broken migration chain. 
There are several options:

- You could try restoring the migration file you edited and re-raking. This is worth a shot and it might work.
- Rollback all migrations to the one before you edited the file. Then create the migration you need and run the rake.
- Depending on how broken the database is, you may just want to start over having learned a painful lesson about Rails database migration files.